# Representing a many-to-many relationship with lookup table in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, many-to-many, fluent-entity-framework

I have a SQL database (which isn't normalized and doesn't have primary keys, only indexes **which I cannot change the schema of**) that has a many-to-many relationship.

Reservations can have many Customers and vice-versa.  The Reservation table is keyed off ReservationID and TransactionLineNumber.  The Customer table has IPCode as its key.

There is a lookup table that is used to create this relationship that has the three keys and nothing else.

Below is my DbContext configuration code:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<ReservationDetail>()
            .HasMany(rd => rd.LinkedCustomers)
            .WithMany(c => c.Reservations)
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.ToTable("r_transaction_detail_ip");
                m.MapLeftKey("reservation_id", "transaction_line_number");
                m.MapRightKey("ip_number");
            });
```

Here are snippets of the classes for each, and their entity configurations:

**Customer**

```
public class Customer
{
    public string IpNumber { get; set; }

    public string CustomerName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ReservationDetail> Reservations { get; set; }
}

        ToTable("ip");
        HasKey(c => c.IpNumber);

        Property(c => c.IpNumber).HasColumnName("ipcode");
        Property(c => c.CustomerName).HasColumnName("displayname");
```

**Reservation**

```
public class ReservationDetail
{
    public string ReservationId { get; set; }

    public short TransactionLineNumber { get; set; }

    ...

    public virtual ICollection<Customer> LinkedCustomers { get; set; } 
}

        ToTable("r_transaction_detail");
        HasKey(rd => new { rd.ReservationId, rd.TransactionLineNumber });

        Property(rd => rd.ReservationId).HasColumnName("reservation_id");
        Property(rd => rd.TransactionLineNumber).HasColumnName("transaction_line_number");
```

### Now for the question/problem

At runtime, I am attempting to get a list of reservations, and each of the related customers on a reservation.  Running the following example code:

```
(this is an IQueryable of ReservationDetail) reservationItems.First().LinkedCustomers.First().CustomerName;
```

throws an exception on the second First() call because LinkedCustomers has no items.  **Looking at the DB I am connecting to, there should be one entry in this list of Customers.**

Any pointers on where my configuration may be bad?

Comment: @GertArnold It's a list of reservations.  Will update question.

Comment: Do the generated SQL statements return the records you expect?

Comment: @GertArnold What's the easiest way to get to the generated SQL?

Comment: EF 6? contex.Database.Log. Else Sql profiler (assuming this is SQL Server).

Comment: @GertArnold I'm running EF6, but when I set that to write to `Console.Write`, I'm not seeing anything in my Output window as expected.  Does 2012/13 not log Console writes to Output anymore?

Comment: Trace.WriteLine or Debug.WriteLine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55875/discussion-between-garrison-neely-and-gert-arnold).

Comment: Any progress on this? It's not simply that lazy loading is disabled? Try `reservationItems.Include(r => r.LinkedCustomers)`.

Comment: @GertArnold Due to time constraints, I had to fall back to building an entity for the lookup table.  Thanks for trying to help.